# How can I make Parse.Query.AND?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, parse-platform, nosql

I need to connect 2 queries in Parse.com with an and, my code is:

```
    var queryDeseo1 = new Parse.Query(DeseosModel);
    queryDeseo1.equalTo("User", Parse.User.current());
    queryDeseo1.equalTo("Deseo", artist);

    queryDeseo1.find({...
```

The result of the `.find` is all the objects with `User = Parse.User.current())` and all the objects with `Deseo = artist` but I want the objects with the two queries together:

`User = Parse.User.current())` and `Deseo = artist`

Comment: was your issue solved?

Answer (score 2):

You've actually got it setup correctly to do an **AND** query. The problem (assuming that your data structure is setup properly) is that your *User* field is a Pointer to the User table. Therefore, you need to query for a User equal to the pointer, as opposed to a User equal to **Parse.User.current()** which will return a string. Something like the following:

```
var userPointer = {
  __type:    'Pointer',
  className: 'User',
  objectId:  Parse.User.current().id
}

queryDeseo1.equalTo('User', userPointer);
```

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios glad to help! :-)

Comment: If you want to go here and answer the same so i can accpet the answer..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700805/two-equalto-in-parse-com-javascript

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios I would but it's been marked as a duplicate.