# Two equalTo in parse.com javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to set two `equalTo` in pares.com javascript.
So the code below, in the function i get the idEvent from another function
and i have a certain idTypeImageEvent that i want also to check if both are true
To bring me the image. The code below doesnt bring me any image and i think that i cant put 2 `equalTo` before one `find()` function

```
function imageTouEvent(eventid) {
    var Event = Parse.Object.extend("Event");
    var eventaki = new Event();
    eventaki.id = eventid;
    var imageEvent = Parse.Object.extend("imageEvent");
    var eikona = new imageEvent();
    eikona.id = "vPdWjmYs2G";
    var queryImageEvent = new Parse.Query(imageEvent);
    queryImageEvent.equalTo("idEvent", eventaki);
    queryImageEvent.equalTo("idTypeImageEvent", eikona);
    queryImageEvent.find({
        success: function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                console.log("mphke");
                var objectImage = results[i];
                var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                img.setAttribute("src", objectImage.get('galleryImageEvent').url());
                img.setAttribute("width", "200");
                img.setAttribute("height", "200");
                img.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
                document.getElementById('conteiner').appendChild(img);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

What is your opinion about the above code? What should i change in it so it can work???
I have tried also

```
queryImageEvent.select("idTypeImageEvent", eikona);

queryImageEvent.equalTo("idTypeImageEvent", eikona);
```

But nothing worked.
In the image below i explain better
I have the idEvent (1) and as you can see i want only to bring a certain (2) idTypeImageEvent and then print the image.
[image]

Comment: Looks like this might be helpful. This is a question about parsing with multiple `equalTo`...https://www.parse.com/questions/parsequeryequalto-or-parsequeryequalto

Comment: @brso05 this is "or" but i want "and"

Comment: Did you check to see if they have an `and` function?

Comment: Yes i've searched for hours and i couldnt find any way to combine them both! @brso05

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737609/how-can-i-make-parse-query-and

Comment: @brso05 wow thanks! it worked now.... it was the only thing that i didnt try.....

Comment: @brso05 answer it so i can accept it

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help! I didn't really answer anything lol I just pointed you in the direction of someone who did. Just upvote the answer I linked to...